# Need help populating table using only JavaScript via HTML user Input

Tags: javascript, html

Please bear with me. I have returned to college for a second career and HTML & JavaScript are new to me. I am trying to complete a simple assignment where I accept user input `numShares` & `numYears` via HTML. I'm trying to use JavaScript to fill in a 3 column table (`Year`, `Start Amount`, and `End Amount`). The only calculation on the user input is to double the `numShares` each year. **Question/Problem:** As it is, I receive no output (or error messages). Any and all guidance is appreciated.

Sample Output:
[image: sample table]

Below is the HTML & JS I have so far:

```js
var amt = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var numYears = document.getElementById("years").value; 
var totalAmt, newE1, newE2, newE3, newText;

elTable = document.getElementById('profits');  // get table

function total() {
 for (var i = 0; i < numYears; i++) {
  
  totalAmt += amt;
  
  newE1 = document.createElement('td');
  newText = document.createTextNode(i);
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  elTable.appendChild(newE1);
  
  newE2 = document.createElement('td');
  newText = document.createTextNode(amt);
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  elTable.appendChild(newE2);

  newE3 = document.createElement('td');
  newText = document.createTextNode(totalAmt);
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  elTable.appendChild(newE3);

 }
}

elAddRow = document.getElementById('total');  // get calculate button
elAddRow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    total();
})
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" name="invest">
  <h2></h2>

  <br>Enter Number of Shares:
  <input type="text" id="qty">
  <br>Enter Years to Invest:
  <input type="text" id="years">
  <br/>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Return" id="total">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</form>

<table id="profits">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Start Amount</th>
      <th>End Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>
<script src="scripts/profits.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: And your actual question is?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I've been going at this for hours. The table isn't being populated when I click on the "Calculate Return" button. There are no errors in the HTML or JS consoles??

Comment: `document.getElementById('qty', 'years');` is not going to work. [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) takes only a single string as 1 parameter and returns a single element, or `null` if the ID is not found in the `document`.

Comment: thanks, I updated the JS. If you have any additional guidance, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It's OK this time because everyone adapted (and the change you made was borderline). Just FYI: Once you have answers, it is frowned upon to change your Question to the extent that it is basically another question to the point that it invalidates answers. Refining the question is good. Adding requested additional information is good. Unless doing either significantly changes the question. Here, the change in how you are attempting to add to the table is borderline. If you do make such changes, *do what you did do* and leave comments on all answers that you have updated the question.

Comment: In my above comment, "significantly changes the question" more or less means the question changes to be sufficiently different such that already existing answers which, prior to the question change, were reasonable answers become invalid, wrong, or no longer match the question. What constitutes such a change is nebulous. Some changes are clearly complete changes to a question, others can be borderline, or seen as either refinements dramatic changes. For more information, there are a bunch of questions on [meta] about this issue (at least one was a Hot Meta Post in the last few/several days).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I honestly didn't realize my updates were a major change. However, I completely get the gist of what you are saying and appreciate you making me aware. I value everyone's time and will make every effort not to waste it, by invalidating previous support. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifying your new code:

Modifying the new code which you edited into the question, you can get to the function code below.  This has quite a bit fewer code comments, but many similar changes as were made to your original code. Please see that code (further below) for those additional comments.

Additional documentation (in addition to the documentation referenced below when modifying your original code):

- [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [HTMLTableElement.insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)
- [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement)
- [HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

```js
function total() {
    //You need to get the user input here, not when the page loads.
    var amt = +document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var numYears = +document.getElementById("years").value; 
    var totalAmt=amt; //Initial investment amount
    var yearStartAmount;

    var elTable = document.getElementById('profits');  // get table

    for (var i = 1; i <= numYears; i++) {
        yearStartAmount = totalAmt;
        totalAmt *= 2; //double the investment

        var newRow = elTable.insertRow();                  // Add a row
        // .textContent can be used when the *only* child is to be a text node.
        newRow.insertCell().textContent = i;               //Add a cell and text content 
        newRow.insertCell().textContent = yearStartAmount; //Add a cell and text content
        newRow.insertCell().textContent = totalAmt;        //Add a cell and text content
    }
}

//Add listener to calculate button
document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click',total);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" name="invest">
  <h2></h2>

  <br>Enter Number of Shares:
  <input type="text" id="qty">
  <br>Enter Years to Invest:
  <input type="text" id="years">
  <br/>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Return" id="total">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</form>

<table id="profits">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Start Amount</th>
      <th>End Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>
<script src="scripts/profits.js"></script>

</html>
```

### Modifying your original code:

You had quite a few problems with your code.  I have made significant modifications to it and added copious amounts of comments to the code to indicate what is being done. Because there were quite a few issues, I have gone significantly beyond what I would normally expect to do in modifying your code. I would suggest that you take a look at this as an example of how it might be possible to accomplish what was desired and then try to modify your own code to be functional.

Some documentation you should look through:

- [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)
- [HTMLTableElement.tBodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies)
- [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

```js
//Use a name for the function that reflects what it does.
function generateTableBodyAndInsertInTable() {
  //Get the input values now.  You were getting them when the page first loaded.
  //  When the page first loads, those values are black because the use has not
  //  supplied the input yet.
  //  The "+" in front of "document" forces the value to be converted to a number
  //  instead of remaining as the text returned from the .value property.
  var investAmount = +document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var numYears = +document.getElementById("years").value;
  var totalInvestment=investAmount; //populate the total with the starting investment
  var table = ''; //A string that will accumulate the HTML text to use as the table body
  //Find the table body element
  var tableBodyEl = document.getElementById('profits').tBodies[0];
  var yearStartAmount; //A variable which will hold the start of year investment amount
  for (var i = 1; i <= numYears; i++) { //Loop through the years, the first is year 1
    yearStartAmount = totalInvestment;
    totalInvestment *= 2; //Double the money each year
    //Add a row of HTML text to table for the current year
    table += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>$' + yearStartAmount + '</td><td>$' 
             + totalInvestment + '</td></tr>';
  }
  //Replace the table body with the HTML text in table. You were doing nothing with
  //  the HTML text you were generating. So, even if your event listener was being
  //  called (which it wasn't), then the rows would not have been added to the table.
  tableBodyEl.innerHTML = table;
}
//Find the element for the calculate return button.  You were passing
//  two strings to getElementById() when you need to pass only one. In addition,
//  neither of the strings was the ID for the Calculate Return button.
//  We really don't need to use a separate variable here because we are only using
//  it one place (the addEventListener() in the next line).
var calculateReturnButtonEl = document.getElementById('total');
//Add the event listener to the Calculate Return button.
//If you are going to call just one function there is no need to wrap that function
//  in yet another anonymous function.  It can be added directly as a listener.
calculateReturnButtonEl.addEventListener('click', generateTableBodyAndInsertInTable);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" name="invest">
  <h2></h2>

  <br>Enter Number of Shares:
  <input type="text" id="qty">
  <br>Enter Years to Invest:
  <input type="text" id="years">
  <br/>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Return" id="total">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</form>

<table id="profits">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Start Amount</th>
      <th>End Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="scripts/profits.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You really didn't have to go to so much trouble, but it is greatly appreciated. I will study your code, as well as the links you provided. It's very important that I learn this...thanks again!

Comment: @Invictus, I hope it helps. I started doing one thing, which lead to another, etc. Basically, it snowballed into getting the code functional.

Comment: @Invictus, I have added an additional snippet which modifies the code you edited into the question. You are getting closer. Manipulating the elements instead of HTML text is better in this case. Which to use in each instance is a trade off. You should be familiar with doing both. However, there are specific methods for adding rows and cells to tables which make it even easier/cleaner (and you were just adding cells, when you needed to be adding a new row with new cells in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Listening for the click event on the element with ID `qty` is probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: I tried listening on ID 'total' which represents the Calculate button (seemed logical), but that gave no output or errors either.

Comment: 'total' is the right ID. Now to look at your `total()` JS function. I don't see where you defined the `table` variable so you need to sort that out. `document.getElementById('profits')` will give you a reference to the table. But `+=` is not the way to amend the table. You might want to look at documentation for `document.createElement(...)` and try appending your new `<tr>`s and `<td>`s using `table.appendChild(...)` and so on.

Comment: I think you are right. I was going down that path a few hours ago then headed in a new direction. I'll go back and try reworking it as you mentioned. Thanks for your time and guidance.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Feel free to keep asking questions as they come up. Trying not to just hand you the solution, since working through the problem will help it stick in your brain better :)

Comment: Hi, updated JS. Think I'm on the right track but still no output or errors. Do I also need to create new <tr> elements? If so, should I do so in HTML or JS? I know using "amt" in the newE2 will have to be adjusted, as that will output the same value each time. I've been at this nearly 12 hours today. It's bedtime! I look forward to any guidance you can offer.  Take care.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm to bed also and away for the weekend, but plenty of folks here should step in as needed. Anyway, yes I'd create the new `tr` element and append the `td`s to that. You're certainly on the right track now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working rewrite of your code:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="invest">
    <h2></h2>

    Enter Number of Shares: <input type="text" id="qty" required><br>
    Enter Years to Invest: <input type="text" id="years" required><br/><br>
    <button type="button" value="Calculate Return" id="total">
        Calculate Return</button>
    <br><br><br>

</form>

<table id="profits">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Start Amount</th>
            <th>End Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tb"> 

    </tbody>

</table>
```

javascript

```
    var totalAmt = 0;
    var table;


    function total() {
        var amt = document.getElementById("qty").value;
        amt = parseInt(amt, 10)
        var numYears = document.getElementById("years").value;

        for (var i = 1; i <= numYears; i++) {
            totalAmt = totalAmt + amt;
            //  alert(totalAmt);
            //  alert(amt);

            // table += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>$' + amt + '</td><td>$' + totalAmt + '</td></tr>';

            var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

            var row = document.createElement('tr');

            var cell_years = document.createElement('td');
            var cell_amt = document.createElement('td');
            var cell_totalAmt = document.createElement('td');

            var text_years = document.createTextNode(i);
            var text_amt = document.createTextNode('$' + amt);
            var text_totalAmt = document.createTextNode('$' + totalAmt);

            cell_years.appendChild(text_years);
            cell_amt.appendChild(text_amt);
            cell_totalAmt.appendChild(text_totalAmt);
            row.appendChild(cell_years);
            row.appendChild(cell_amt);
            row.appendChild(cell_totalAmt);

            tbody.appendChild(row);

        }


    }

    // call total() when button clicked
    var attachee = document.getElementById('total');
    attachee.addEventListener('click', total);

    // var elAddRows = document.getElementById('qty', 'years');
    // elAddRows.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //     total();
    // });
```

here is a working demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mABPdo?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you very much! The more I study, the more it seems there are multiple ways to do the same things. I've been going at it 12+ hours today, but promise I'll go over all of your code to make sure I fully understand it tomorrow!